# Chart.js 2.9.4 - error using bundle from CDN - "chart is not defined"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, chart.js

I have a react app with typescript and want to use Chart.js version 2.9.4 externally.

Unfortunately I get the following error in the browser running my bundle.js file with `node index.js`:

```
bundle.js:116 Uncaught ReferenceError: chart is not defined
    at bundle.js:116
    at bundle.js:216
    at bundle.js:216
```

For instance my `index.js` is just an express server to serve the dist folder:

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const root = `${__dirname}/dist`
app.use(express.static(root))
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

This is the body my template.prod.html file:

```
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

And in webpack.prod.js I have the following configuration:

```
  externals: {
    react: 'React',
    axios: 'axios',
    moment: 'moment',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    'react-router-dom': 'ReactRouterDOM',
    'chart.js': 'chart.js'
  },
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe I struggled with it, but the key is from where I import the lib, in the case "chart.js" and the value is what I import, in the case Chart, not "chart.js".

Correct should be:

```js
  externals: {
    react: 'React',
    axios: 'axios',
    moment: 'moment',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    'react-router-dom': 'ReactRouterDOM',
    'chart.js': 'Chart'
  }
```